# What is this tree and do I need a pollinating partner?

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees, pollination

I recently moved and I found this tree/shrub in my backyard. It is about 1.2m tall

[image]

It produced a single fruit which looked a lot like a cherry, although it had plenty of flowers.

My main question is: what is this tree?

And in case it is an edible fruit tree:

- why did it produce just one single fruit?
- Is it that I need a pollinating partner?
- If so what would be suitable pollinating partner?

Here are some more photographs:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what are of the world is the tree in?

Comment: What were the flowers like earlier in the year - clusters of pink or white blossom,  or more like creamy white candles?  Has this tree previously been pruned back?

Comment: It's Lancaster (UK), north-west of England. As far as I remember the flowers were white. i don't know if it's ever been pruner nor how old it is

Answer (score 4):

If we look closely at the bottom of the leaf blade there appears to be a gland. This could indicate a type of cherry. Further than that it will be hard to be more specific.

If you are really lucky there may be some paint marks at the base of the tree. In the nursery the grafters often keep track of what scion has been grafted to what stock by marking with a different colour paint stripe. However these tend to disappear over time. If you can see something, check with local nurseries to see if they can help you pinpoint which one you have.

Cross pollination is generally required for cherries, and you need to know which variety you have in order to choose a suitable partner. There are a number of charts published to try to help (for example http://treefruit.wsu.edu/orchard-management/pollination/). It is possible there is a partner in your locality but some distance away which is why there has been only one fruit. The density of suitable pollen is very low in your area.

Comment: Assuming it is a cherry, and noting that bloom was in  April and May (more April), what would be the best bet? Or is it not worth it, I should just get rid of it and get two compatible cherries?

Comment: Clip a small branch, take it along to the nursery local to you with the best reputation, present the branch and your photos, ask them what they think it might be. Take the twig into the inventory beds and see if you can match it up easily. They may be able to recommend an action or a partner tree that would suit your purposes.